# MySQL: can't connect to 127.0.0.1 but localhost works

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

In an Ubuntu 14.04 with mysql 5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 when trying to connect to mysql with this:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Although if I connect without the host it works properly:

```
 mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
azureuser@host:/var/www/website$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1354
Server version: 5.5.58-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

I would need to be able to use 127.0.0.1 as host instead of localhost, any idea on why this could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Permissions are configured differently for local and remote... by default, root can't connect remotely. This is a good thing, on average. Try `SHOW GRANT` and look at the documentation for `GRANT`. Also, be aware that MySQL's root is not Ubuntu's root, but I think most people get that.

Comment: @BrianDewhirst nope, in this case you would get an access denied error message, not a can't connect one.